# Calculation with timestamp in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to perform simple calculations with the datetime in my code to check

1. if there's a recent transaction in the data based on the Last_transaction_date if it is < 2 years.
2. if the account is date to be paid based on whether the Pay_date is greater than the current date.

I also created a Duration column to calculate the number of years between the current date and last_transaction_date. The value of this needs to be rounded up to 2dp.

Below is the code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Pay_Date' : [20220131, 20201231, 20191130, 20210831, 20211031, 20211231],
        'Last_transaction_date': [20191202, 20190220, 20191127, 20190829, 20200323, 20211223]}

datetime = pd.DataFrame(data)

current_date = pd.to_datetime('today')

#Check if the duration between current date and last transaction date is <= 2 years
datetime['Duration'] = ((current_date - datetime['Last_transaction_date'])/365).round(2)
datetime['Last_transaction_date']= pd.to_datetime(datetime['Last_transaction_date'], format='%Y%m%d')
datetime['Recent_Transactions']= datetime['Last_transaction_date'].apply(lambda x: 'YES' if (datetime['Duration'] <= pd.Timedelta(2, 'Y')).any() else 'NO')

#Check if the Pay_date is greater than the current date
datetime['Pay_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datetime['Pay_Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
datetime['To_Pay'] = datetime['Pay_Date'].apply(lambda x: 'YES' if (datetime['Pay_Date'].any() > current_date) else 'NO')

print(datetime)
```

and it has a TypeError saying 'Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.'

However, the output I'm trying to achieve is:

```
   Pay_Date    Last_transaction_date    Duration    Recent_Transactions    To_Pay 
0  20220131        20191202              1.76            YES                YES
1  20201231        20190220              2.54            NO                 NO
2  20191130        20191127              1.78            YES                NO 
3  20210831        20190829              2.02            NO                 NO
4  20211031        20200323              1.46            YES                YES
5  20211231        20211223              0.30            YES                YES
```

You can use this link to check on the calculation of duration and then manually divide the number of days by 365 to get the number of years.
https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=23&m1=12&y1=2021&d2=6&m2=9&y2=2021

If there's a better link you found, please share in the comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring at the line where you're trying to create the "Duration" column because the "Last_transaction_date" column is being interpreted as `int`.

Note: `pd.Timedelta` does not accept years as a valid unit anymore. I have therefore used 730 (365*2) days.

```
#Convert the date columns to datetime format
datetime['Last_transaction_date']= pd.to_datetime(datetime['Last_transaction_date'], format='%Y%m%d')
datetime['Pay_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datetime['Pay_Date'], format='%Y%m%d')

#Check if duration between current date and last transaction date is <= 2 years
datetime["Duration"] = ((current_date-datetime['Last_transaction_date']).dt.days/365).round(2)
datetime['Recent_Transactions'] = (datetime["Duration"]<=2).replace({True: "YES", False: "NO"})

#Check if the Pay_date is greater than the current date
datetime['To_Pay'] = (datetime["Pay_Date"]>current_date).replace({True: "YES", False: "NO"})

>>> datetime
    Pay_Date Last_transaction_date  Duration Recent_Transactions To_Pay
0 2022-01-31            2019-12-02      1.76                 YES    YES
1 2020-12-31            2019-02-20      2.55                  NO     NO
2 2019-11-30            2019-11-27      1.78                 YES     NO
3 2021-08-31            2019-08-29      2.02                  NO     NO
4 2021-10-31            2020-03-23      1.46                 YES    YES
5 2021-12-31            2021-12-23     -0.30                 YES    YES
```